# SQL Server 2008: MERGE command on a table that has a trigger causes an error

Tags: sql-server, merge, windows-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that uses the `MERGE` command to synchronize `dbo.tableA` with `[mylinkedserver].dbo.TableA`.

`TableA` has an insert/update trigger associated with it. To keep things really simple all the trigger does is

```
print 'I am a simple trigger because i dont want to cause errors'
```

When the SP is executed (thru a .net windows application), it throws this error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MyLinkedServer"
>   returned message "No transaction is
>   active."

If I delete the trigger and execute the stored proc again, it executes absolutely fine.

The stored procedure also runs fine (with the trigger) if i run it through SSMS.

MSDTC is enabled on both servers.

Server is Windows 2008 server, SQL Server 2008 with service pack 2.

Why would a trigger cause this error ?!?!??

Comment: Possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869977/sql-server-2008-merge-statement-how-to-disable-instead-of-insert-trigger-to-al

Answer (score 2):

Trigger implementation with Merge is a little tricky.  It boils down to "for each action specified in the merge statement there must be a trigger".

TechNet Says "If the target table has an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger defined on it for an insert, update, or delete action performed by a MERGE statement, then it must have an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger for all of the actions specified in the MERGE statement."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I made 3 separate triggers for insert,update, delete(as these are the operations performed by the MERGE command). All with simple print statements. Still no luck.  There is no INSTEAD OF in the triggers.

Comment: I also tried with just one trigger for only inserts. Still no luck.

Comment: Does this mean that you removed all the linked server stuff and that just a merge statement with a trigger on the table is causing an error?  Has the error message changed?

Comment: No the linked server stuff is still there. I am still trying to MERGE dbo.tableA with [mylinkedserver].dbo.TableA. I just changed the triggers on dbo.tableA.

Comment: if I use different tigger for insert and update is working fine