# Getting Error :MERGE statement has an INSTEAD OF trigger on some, but not all, of the actions specified in the MERGE statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a 'instead of insert' trigger on a table to generate custom unique code and on that same table inserting bulk data by store procedure but some how getting error as below :

> The target 'xyz' of the MERGE statement has an INSTEAD OF trigger on some, but not all, of the actions specified in the MERGE statement. In a MERGE statement, if any action has an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger on the target, then all actions must have enabled INSTEAD OF triggers

Any input or comment on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; this is very much one of the far more descriptive errors from SQL Server. What part of the error do you not understand? You don't appear to have asked a question here, just stated you want input or comments; what is your question?

Comment: @Larnu apologize for inconvenience. Actually, I did understand merge statement as  could not found that statement in store procedure by mistake. Thanks for correct me.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is very clear - When using `merge`, `instead of` triggers must be applied for all or none of the actions the `merge` statement may perform.

If your `merge` have an `insert` when not matched, and an `update` when matched, the target table must have either `instead of insert` as well as an `instead of update` triggers, or none of them.

This is also well documented in the `merge` page on Microsoft docs, under the title [Trigger Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#trigger-implementation):

> If the target table has an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger defined on it for an insert, update, or delete action performed by a MERGE statement, then it must have an enabled INSTEAD OF trigger for all of the actions specified in the MERGE statement.

Comment: Interestingly (in case anyone reads the above MS info above decides they want to just disable the trigger) then have a look at the following, as you'll likely need to disable it in another SP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869977/sql-server-2008-merge-statement-how-to-disable-instead-of-insert-trigger-to-al